# ObjectListView - FormatRow Event Not Working For ForeColor

Tags: vb.net, formatting, row, objectlistview

I am trying to format a row in an ObjectListView using the FormatRow event and set the entire row a different ForeColor based on a value, however, to no avail.

My code:

```
Private Sub lsv_OpenTickets_FormatRow(sender As Object, e As FormatRowEventArgs) Handles lsv_OpenTickets.FormatRow
    Dim tkt As Ticket = DirectCast(e.Model, Ticket)
    If tkt.due = "Overdue" Then
        e.Item.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(252, 146, 156)
    End If
End Sub
```

Only seems to set the first Item in the row to the specified color and every other SubItem is painted with the default color.

If I change my code to:

```
e.Item.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(252, 146, 156)
```

Then it paints the entire row correctly as a back color.  It just doesn't seem to work for the ForeColor.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong?  Or missed something maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out that the e.Item.ForeColor only seems to apply formatting to the first SubItem in the row - not all SubItems like I would've thought.  Not sure if this is intentional or a bug or if I'm coding something incorrectly, but to me 'Item' corresponds to the entire row, whereas SubItem corresponds to individual cells.

Anyway, to overcome my issue, I modified my code to the following:

```
Private Sub lsv_OpenTickets_FormatRow(sender As Object, e As FormatRowEventArgs) Handles lsv_OpenTickets.FormatRow
    Dim tkt As Ticket = DirectCast(e.Model, Ticket)
    If tkt.due = "OVERDUE" Then
        For Each sb As OLVListSubItem In e.Item.SubItems
            sb.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(252, 146, 159)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

This now gives me the results I required and also works well with the FormatCell event, as individual cell formatting will override the row formatting.

Comment: I went this way as well. My first thought was to set `args.Item.UseItemStyleForSubItems` to true, but that is an original ListViewItem property and doesn't seem to affect the OLV.

Comment: Looks like it could be a bug, but a couple of ways to get round it... [link](https://sourceforge.net/p/objectlistview/discussion/812923/thread/a34809f8/)